# iOS Simulator failed to install the application msg with successful build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a Problem with xcode in running the app in simulator.

- There are no warnings/errors in the code.
- The build is success full in simulator.

Problem :
After the success full build, xcode shows a message saying "iOS Simulator failed to install the application."

Actions : result :

- On google search i got similar problems reported with following solutions :

  1. Reset Content and settings " for iOS simulator " : not success full in my case
  2. Close and restart Xcode : not success full in my case
  3. Restarting Mac : not success full in my case.
  4. Cleaning the build DIRECTORY by "cmd+shft+k" : not success full in my case.

xcode version : 5.1.1
mac OS version : 10.9
iOS version used in simulator : 7.1

Any Suggestion Would be a great help. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried deleting Derived data and restarting simulator?

Comment: Do you have free space on your primary disk?

Comment: Did you try other simulators ? Does this happen in EVERY simulator ?

Comment: Are there any 3rd party libraries that you use?

Comment: @ Polina : I have deleted the derived data and restated the simulator, still the problem exists

Comment: @ gWiz :I have the disk Space required, @ HpTerm :Downloading different simulator, @ Amel Mahmuzić:  no 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one for the help and suggestions,

I just solved the problem by reinstalling xcode from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reason. it's not clear from your question still you can try following

1> make sure you do not have any long task running on your main thread in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

2> try with different simulator

3> Try after deleting derived data

4> Try it in device if possible. If it works on device than you do not need to worry. Probably it's intermittent issue and will be resolve.